# Immediate SQL - Command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm having troubles running this Function in Oracle. I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I keep getting "SQL command not properly ended line at 18". I think it has something to do with my Immediate SQL but I'm not entirely positive. Any thoughts?

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION COMPARE_USER(
indexNumber IN varchar,
firstName IN varchar,
lastName IN varchar,
email IN varchar,
department IN varchar,
userLocation IN varchar,
userType IN varchar,
active IN varchar
)
RETURN CHAR 
IS
  tableName varchar(50) := 'TEST_USER';
  boolCheck char;
  rowCount int;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tableName ||
  ' WHERE INDEX_NUMBER  = ' || indexNumber ||
  ' AND FIRST_NAME  = ' || firstName ||
  ' AND LAST_NAME  = ' || lastName ||
  ' AND EMAIL  = ' || email ||
  ' AND DEPARTMENT  = ' || department ||
  ' AND USER_LOCATION  = ' || userLocation ||
  ' AND USER_TYPE  = ' || userType ||
  ' AND ACTIVE  = ' || active
  INTO rowCount;

  IF rowCount = 0 Then
    boolCheck := 'N';
  Else
    boolCheck := 'Y';
  End If;
RETURN boolCheck;
END COMPARE_USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try re-writing the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, as follows:

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tableName ||
  ' INTO rowCount'
  ' WHERE INDEX_NUMBER  = ' || indexNumber ||
  ' AND FIRST_NAME  = ' || firstName ||
  ' AND LAST_NAME  = ' || lastName ||
  ' AND EMAIL  = ' || email ||
  ' AND DEPARTMENT  = ' || department ||
  ' AND USER_LOCATION  = ' || userLocation ||
  ' AND USER_TYPE  = ' || userType ||
  ' AND ACTIVE  = ' || active
```